# How to get Debian to detect my Audigy 2

Tags: debian, audio

I started my PC this morning and noticed that I had no sound. Since last using the sound card successfully, I had installed `openssh-server`, but I suspect this is unrelated.

I think my PC isn't picking up the sound card. Typing `lspci -nn | grep -i audio` produces the following:

> 04:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device [1002:aab0]

I don't know what that is, but it's not my sound card (I do have an ATI video card though).

I tried taking out the physical sound card, cleaning the PCI slot, and putting it back in, to no effect. I do kick the case by accident sometimes, and it is an old card, so I wouldn't rule out that it just died, but I'd like to be sure (I have no other PC on which to check the card, and I don't have Windows installed...).

When I go to `System Tools -> Preferences -> System Settings -> Sound` I see only a `Dummy Output` device.

I tried following [these instructions](https://wiki.debian.org/snd-emu10k1) and ran the following:

```
aptitude install alsa-base alsa-utils
adduser yourusername audio #this said I've already been added
```

Then I ran `alsamixer` and confirmed that nothing was muted, and tried running `speaker-test -t sine -f 440 -c 2` but couldn't hear anything. Running `lspci` produced the same output as before.

Does anyone have tips on how I can further diagnose this and track down the problem to hopefully confirm whether this is a software issue or not?

Comment: To be clear, you were using the sound card successfully, but then it just stopped working for no reason? That does point to a hardware problem. Perhaps try a different Os or live CD on the same machine, or try the card in a different machine?

Comment: @FaheemMitha yeah that's pretty much what happened. I'll give the live machine a try (I don't have a different machine though...)